# Creating References.cs problem in VS2008

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

Hi am learning C# in VS2008 platform.I have problem with Windows Mobile project which include .NET Compact Framework 3.5.

When I adding a web reference or update it,there is an error comes with "'MSDiscoCodeGenerator' failed".Here a snapshot of error:
[image]

When I look in web references,I noticed that there is no References.cs file exists.How can I solve it?I have uninstalled and installed .NET CF 3.5 ,but nothing has changed.My platform is VS2008 running on Win 7 OS.

Note:Sorry for red drawings on snapshot,it's for my company's security restrictions.

My best regards and thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to get more information, do you have the VS 2008 Service Pack 1 installed ? If not, you should try installing it.

Comment: Yes,it is installed.I run some other projects without problem before.They have  web references included,too.There is no problem with adding or updating web reference.My problem is occured with Windows Mobile side.

Answer (score 0):

On this post it is suggested to uninstall, then clean up the registry and then install. I know it is not a quick solution, but you may try if nothing else work.

[See this Article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joy/archive/2008/08/26/the-custom-tool-msdiscocodegenerator-failed-while-building-projects.aspx)

Comment: I have read this article and did what they say.:)                     But maybe I will give it a second try if no one else come with different solution.Thanks.